# How to use Cocos2dJS to connect to a Socket.IO server?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d, node.js, websocket

How can I connect to a `nodejs socket.io` server from a `cocos2djs` game? I've google all the way to no avail. I tried this but it does not work:

```
socket = io.connect('http://192.168.254.102:7714');
if ( socket === undefined ) {
    cc.log("Could not connect to socket.io");
} else {
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('join', {username: 'Android Application'})
    });
}
```

I read in the docs that there's a module called `SocketIO` for doing that, but there's not enough info on how to use it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the result? undefined or some other error?

Comment: SocketIO `undefined`, after searching more I found out that the dev team did not expose SocketIO from cpp to js yet as they did with the other cocos2dx components. A little discuss here: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/does-jsb-support-socket-io/10259/4 . I also a found a similar discussion on github, but I cant find it again.

Comment: What stops you from writing your own networking system?

Answer (score -1):

try opening a new thread like in this video tut and use that for your connections.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6G_W54zuadg

there may be some useful info in this video hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but as you can read in my question, thats not exactly what I am looking for.